# Laravel 9 nwidart/laravel-modules issue Console\ShowModelCommand not found, This probem are solved

Tags: laravel

Error

```
  Class "Illuminate\Database\Console\ShowModelCommand" not found
```

```
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\vendor\nwidart\laravel-modules\src\Commands\ModelShowCommand.php:9
      5▕ use Illuminate\Database\Console\ShowModelCommand;
      6▕ use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
      7▕
      8▕ #[AsCommand('module:model-show', 'Show information about an Eloquent model in modules')]
  ➜   9▕ class ModelShowCommand extends ShowModelCommand
     10▕ {
     11▕
     12▕
     13▕     /**

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:571
      include()
```

please run this command and its work properly
composer require nwidart/laravel-modules "9.*"

Comment: Check your composer.json, the version of `nwidart/laravel-modules` should be 9.x. it all depends on your Laravel version, but this error is common with a **newer** version of `nwidart/laravel-modules` and an **older** version of Laravel. After changing that version, run `composer update` so that you'll get your proper version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.